# is there any way to translate the color expressed by numpy on python as [[[255 0 0 0]]] which is white, to [[[255 255 255 255]]](RBGA)

Tags: python, numpy, colors, clipboard, numpy-ndarray

The first thing, to locate them, is that I have an image of a white pixel, in RGB that pixel would be as an array in python using numpy like this: [[255 255 255 255]]; if I open clip studio paint and copy the "layer" of the image numpy returns me reading the data of the image this: [[[255 0 0 0]]]; When I save it, a gray image appears in python. I know that the layer can be read since inkscape does it well when copying and pasting, I understand that windos removes transparencies when copying; use PIL,numpy and ImageGrab.grabclipboard() to copy the image from clipboard. the question is, is there any way to translate the color expressed by numpy as [[[255 0 0 0]]] which is white, to [[255 255 255 255]]; I must clarify that if inkscape does it, it is because it recognizes something in the data of the clip studio layer and if it is readable for inkscape, it is probably also readable in python, I must also clarify, that it is not just locating the numbers so that it gives, already that for example this image that is bigger is the same, but it is not saved in the same way.

#-------------------------------------------
from clip studio:

```
[[[  0   0   0 255]
  [255 255 255 255]
  [255 255 255 255]]

 [[  1   1   1 255]
  [  1   1   1 255]
  [255 255 255 255]]

 [[255   0   0   0]
  [  0 255   0   0]
  [  0   0 255   0]]]
```

#-------------------------------------------
from an open image as RBG

```
[[[ 0 0 0]
  [255 255 255]
  [255 255 255]]

 [[ 0 0 0]
  [255 255 255]
  [255 255 255]]

 [[ 1 1 1]
  [ 1 1 1]
  [255 255 255]]])
```

#-------------------------------------------
from an open image as RBGA

```
[[[  0   0   0 255]
  [255 255 255 255]
  [255 255 255 255]]

 [[  0   0   0 255]
  [255 255 255 255]
  [255 255 255 255]]

 [[  1   1   1 255]
  [  1   1   1 255]
  [255 255 255 255]]]
```

it's a black three-pixel L on a white background.
It is to clarify that the error sometimes generates random colors on the right or left, or it can also crop an image and return it with half on the right and the other half on the left

example code

```
from PIL import Image as pilImage
import numpy as np
from PIL import ImageGrab

#with image
im = pilImage.open("l.png")#RGB
im = im.convert("RGBA")#also convert  RBG to "RBGA" or "RGB"
datas = np.asarray(im)
print(datas)
im.show()
#----------------------------------------------------------
print("#----------------------------------------------------------")
#----------------------------------------------------------
#with clip studio paint layer
#if inkscape collects the data and turns it into
#an image i guess python could read it too

#first put the imagen on clip studio paint
#second copy the layer from clip studio

imgS = ImageGrab.grabclipboard()
datasClip=np.asarray(imgS)
print(datasClip)
imgS.show()
```

the image is 3 pixels, it's hard to see but here it is[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbnDf.png)

Comment: it has four values - so it is `RGBA`, not `RGB`. Maybe first get `image[:,:,:3]` to skip layer `A` (transparency).

Comment: it is numpy array - maybe it will work `image[ image == [255,0,0] ] = [255, 255, 255]`

Comment: I also thought that it is RGBA but it is not the case.

Comment: here is place for comments and it doesn't have to be sulution. But it can make problem - array has values `RGBA` and you can't put `RGB` - all items in array need 4 values. So first you have to crop from `RGBA` to `RGB`

Comment: data from `clip studio` doesn't look like image but rather like 3 objects: first object `[[[255 0 0 0]]]`, second object `[[[255 255 255]]]` and later image `[[[ 0 0 0 255] ...`